# ASP.net how to use a CompareValidator to compare a textbox input to a column in database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Is there a way to use CompareValidator to validate user input against data in a database table? For example, I have a table STUDENT that contains a column Student_ID. I need to display an error message if a user entered Student_ID value in a textbox that does not exist in the database.

Comment: instead you can use custom validator

Answer (score 0):

```
{cn.Open(); 
//q = "select * from tblStudent where Student_ID='" + TextBox8.Text + "'"; 
cmd = new SqlCommand(q, cn); 
ds = new DataSet(); 
ad = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblproductorder where Student_ID='" + TextBox8.Text + "'", cn); 
ad.Fill(ds, "tblStudent "); 
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) 
{ 
Label1.Visible = true; 
Label1.Text = " Not Available"; 
TextBox8.Text = ""; 
TextBox8.Focus(); 
} 
else 
{ 
Label1.Visible = true; 
Label1.Text = " Available"; 


}
```

use this in textchanged event of a text box

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Amarnath! IS there anyway to do that with VB?

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/ you can use this to convert and if it helped please mark it answer, it would be useful for someone